# Error while installing edx on debian squeeze

Tags: debian, ansible

I am installing edx platform on debian squeeze with anisible at the middle of the process of installation I get this error :

```
TASK: [supervisor | create a symlink for supervisor cfg] ********************** 
ok: [localhost] => (item=/edx/app/supervisor/supervisord.conf)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/edx/app/supervisor/conf.d)

TASK: [supervisor | start supervisor] ***************************************** 
failed: [localhost] => {"failed": true, "item": ""}
msg: cannot find 'service' binary or init script for service,  possible typo in service name?, aborting

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
       to retry, use: --limit @/root/edx_sandbox.retry

localhost                  : ok=42   changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

I don't know what is the problem? can anybody help me?thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*Answering regarding the error message* "cannot find 'service' binary", *which was part of the original title*:

The binary `service` is in `/usr/sbin/`,
and that directory is not allways in PATH.

So, maybe you just need to add it?

`/usr/sbin/` is normaly in PATH of root,
but not for other users - not sure you did run it as root from the output you show.

(Turned out that this was not the real problem here, but could still be helpfull in other cases when looking for the error message. Leave a comment if I should better delete it, I wouldn't object.)

Comment: no,I am root.here is my $PATH : `$PATH`:`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Comment: What does "which service" say?

Comment: /usr/sbin/service

Comment: Good, so not the problem I thought...

Comment: yes.should be.but I am root user and get this error.

Comment: What about the second part of the error message, can you find the init script? Something like "/etc/init.d/edx"?

Comment: there is many files in there. but I can't find `edx` file

Comment: Hmm... so either it's just not yet installed, but looking for it - but could be about some different service. Possibly you need to install some dependeny before, that provides some service?

Comment: what should be changed in title ?

Comment: Yes, looks good. I will delete some of my comments here that are no longer relevant. So there will be some of yours in between you could delete too.